# Regex Operation not returning specific values

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using following Regex Operation

```
(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s|internal\s|)?[\s\w]*\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:(ref\s|in\s|out\s)?\s*(?<parameterType>[\w\?\[\]]+)\s+(?<parameter>\w+)\s*,?\s*)+\)
```

it is working fine on method like

```
public ResponseViewModel ResponseDetails(
    ResponseViewModelContext responseViewModelContext)
```

but if there is any List in either return type or parameter it is not matching as expected.

i.e following method is not working

```
public List<ResponesViewModel> ResponseDetails(
    List<ResponesViewModelContext> responseViewModelContext)
```

[Link for Online Regex Tried](https://regex101.com/r/SqAFgb/1)

Comment: What did you try? There's something there that's obvious even to somebody who doesn't know regexes, *if* he made even the slightest effort to read the thing, so can I assume you made no effort at all?

Comment: I tried for the last 3 hours with those tags. but it didn't work so I posted here. FYI Question is having all the details of what i've tried and the link where I've tried. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had to add the `<>` brackets characters to the regex.

`(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s|internal\s|)?[\s\w<>]*\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:(ref\s|in\s|out\s)?\s*(?<parameterType>[\w<>\?\[\]]+)\s+(?<parameter>\w+)\s*,?\s*)+\)`

[Link for regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwI6.png)